# Undeleting my own question also undeleted my answers and now I can't delete them anymore

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, deleted-posts, vote-to-undelete

Here's the sequence:

1. I asked a question (poll type) and gave four answers for voting.
2. Someone else gave an answer as well.
3. Someone pointed out it was a dupe.
4. I tried to delete the question - it said there were too many answers.
5. I deleted all my answers.
6. I deleted the question successfully.
7. I undeleted the question to leave a comment as to why I deleted it.

Now, all the answers are back with one delete vote each and I can't delete them again since I already voted. And I'm now stuck on step 4 above.

I would think the deleted answers should stay deleted even if I undelete the question. I certainly think I shouldn't lose the power to delete my own answers.

Comment: Sounds like a different kind of Necromancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention indicating what you want done, and it will get done.

Answer (score 1):

First, do not delete dupes light-heartedly. When closed they are pointers to the original question. If you didn't find it, other will have this problem, too.

Second, flag your question for moderator attention, if you still want to delete it. They should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, go ahead and blame me. I posted a comment for one of your answers. That's blocking you from deleting them. :-)

Btw, don't delete dupes but just close them. If a Q is a duplicate then the topic is popular and there's a chance someone else will also ask the same thing. With these dupes in the index, it's more likely that others will notice that the topic has already been covered.

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble at all deleting this post even if there is a comment. Try it.

Comment: I don't actually get a close button over here, just delete. It may be that I need more rep to do it. You bods might have to vote to close it for me as a dupe. Knock yourselves out :-)

Comment: Noth this question of course, I mean this one : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23269/possible-future-sites-for-the-so-engine

Comment: Which has now gone, so don't bother trying to follow the link :-)